# Rights to install programs on any machine on a Windows domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions, windows-sbs-2011

How do I grant a Windows user the rights to install programs on any machine (including servers)? Does a specific role exist for this purpose?

Our corporate network is based on Windows Small Business Server 2011.

Comment: Rights to install a machine? I don't understand what that means.

Comment: @joeqwerty: Thanks for the comment, I have improved the question.